# How to count user questions?

Tags: mysql

I'm using ClearDB Mysql and got the following error: User XXXX has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 18000)]

I know to check the max_questions we can do: `select user, max_questions from mysql.user;`

How can I count the number of questions a user has made?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use select count(max_question) from mysql.user

Comment: That query doesn't work

Comment: I think this is a valid question and should not have been closed, the question is clearly stated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message tells you. You can perform 18,000 "questions" an hour. You've reached the limit, therefore the limit is the number done.

More generically you can use the [SHOW STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html) command:

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Questions'
```

This, according to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Questions), shows...

> The number of statements executed by the server. As of MySQL 5.1.31,
>   this includes only statements sent to the server by clients and no
>   longer includes statements executed within stored programs, unlike the
>   Queries variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And that variable is reset hourly? daily?

Comment: According to the mysql docs it is counting the questions of the last hour: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html