# MySQL error User has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1226
>   User 'bb99ddb719cd2f' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource
>   (current value: 3600) in execute().

Earlier code was working file but suddenly it has started giving errors at every `execute()`.

Here is my code:

Actual file:

```
<?php 
$sql="SELECT count(job_status.is_approved) as is_approved 
    from job_status 
    WHERE job_status.job_id=:job_id and job_status.is_approved=1";
$sth=$conn->prepare($sql); 
$sth->bindValue("job_id",$job_id); 
try { 
    $sth->execute();
} 
catch(Exception $e) { 
    Rollbar::report_exception($e); 
} 
$res=$sth->fetchAll(); 
$stats=$res[0]['is_approved']; 
$status=$stats?'1':'0'; 
return $status;
```

Db connection file:

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php'); 
try { 
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_DATABASE"; 
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD); 
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $conn->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
} 
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Post your code too!!

Comment: please add your code, so someone can debug it.

Comment: Actual file

<?php

$sql="SELECT count(job_status.is_approved) as is_approved from job_status WHERE job_status.job_id=:job_id and job_status.is_approved=1";

$sth=$conn->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue("job_id",$job_id);
try{$sth->execute();}
catch(Exception $e){
  Rollbar::report_exception($e);
 }
$res=$sth->fetchAll();
$stats=$res[0]['is_approved'];
$status=$stats?'1':'0';

return $status;

Comment: db connection file

<?php
require_once('config.php');
try {
 $dsn = "mysql:host=$DB_HOST; dbname=$DB_DATABASE";
 $conn = new PDO($dsn, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $conn->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>

Comment: Looks like you should upgrade your host. The error thrown about "max_questions" means that you MySQL server has exceeded it's capacity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count user questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121250/how-to-count-user-questions)

Comment: This is uploaded on heroku thats why it is giving this error. When ever i am using execute() then it is giving this error.

Answer (score 4):

Some servers have query limit same is the case with heroku in cleardb i.e., 3600 QPH. So to resolve this issue we bought the paid version of cleardb to extend the query limit.