# How to display/get value of the remaining 'max_questions' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have researched the error #1226 exceeded 'max_questions'.

Different answers show how to reset the number to a different value or unlimited.

None show how to get the current value of questions used so it would be possible to throttle the process.

How do I display the current value of the used 'questions'? 
Also, as I understand it, it is a cumulative amount for the last 60 minutes. So waiting 1 minute will give you some queries back. Is that correct?

NOTE: I am not questioning how to get the SETTING value ... I want the current number of queries/questions that are 'charged' against the account.

Comment: [Is the answer here what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17121250/how-to-count-user-questions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have a quick search, you would have landed on to this [page](https://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-modify-the-max_questions-resource-value-in-mysql/)

Nonetheless, I will still be pointing you to the query that will provide you the details that you are looking for:

- Connect to the `MySQL` database via a command prompt or a GUI based tool
- Switch to the database that you want to use on `MySQL`
- Then retrieve the User information from the `MySQL`'s `user` table using the query below

  ```
  SELECT user, max_questions 
  FROM mysql.user;
  ```

The query above should point you to the value of the `max-questions` for the user that you got the error for.

In a more generic way, you could query for the MySQL parameters like the following, using a conditional `WHERE` clause:

```
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'questions'
```

You can follow the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Questions) for further clarifications on how to use and what parameters could be used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the select you show is the SETTING ... NOT the current value. But thanks for the info.  Also in the FROM it needs to be FROM mysql.user;

Comment: @PCoughlin, modified my answer based on your inputs!

Comment: after your update by adding the second part of the answer, it shows the current USED.

Comment: Glad that I could help, @PCoughlin